# overloaded constructors one with two parameters and one with none

Tags: java, parameters, constructor

Design and then create a Rectangle class that has overloaded constructors. The first constructor requires no
parameters. The second has two parameters, one for length and a second for width. Member variables store
the length and width of the rectangle, and member methods assign and retrieve the length and width and
return the area and perimeter of the rectangle. Test the class by writing appropriate client code.

This is a assignment given to me, and i cannot quite understand how to begin something like this, it is only part one of five and i would appreciate some help.

Comment: Do you realize that you didn't say anything about the language your assignment it's supposed to be implemented? :-)

Comment: For a paramaterless constructor, you'd want to initialize the variables with a default value or (more likely) just leave them as a 0.

Comment: so basically just a variable?

Comment: @CST-Link I think this is a pretty language agnostic question. I thought about that too, but hey, I don't want to do his homework for him, so giving general advice rather than code samples is probably the way to go anyway. :)

Comment: Thank you, but how am i to make a constructor with two parameters?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: @Pharylon I agree that "i cannot quite understand how to begin" doesn't depend on the language. However, since the assignment explains *exactly* what the two constructors should do, I assumed that the issue is syntactical, i.e. formulating in an artificial language what was said in natural language. Hence the language question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Rectangle class
class Rectangle{
  private int length;
  private int width;

  Rectangle(){
    this.length=1; // assuming default length=1
    this.width=1; // assuming default width=1
  }

  Rectangle(int length, int width){
    this.length=length; 
    this.width=width; 
  }

int area(){
   return length*width;
}
int perimeter(){
  return 2*(length+width);
}
}


// test class

public class TestRectangle{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Rectangle r1= new Rectangle();
        System.out.println("Area of r1: "+ r1.area());
        Rectangle r2= new Rectangle(2,3);
        System.out.println("Perimetr of r2: "+ r2.perimeter());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/
//       Classes (I)
//         Overloading constructors

#include <cstdlib>  // contains EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <iostream> // cout

// define class
class Rectangle
{
  int width, height;

  public:
    Rectangle ( );           // default constructor
    Rectangle ( int, int );  // overload constructor
    int area ( void ) { return ( width * height ); }
};

// default constructor
Rectangle::Rectangle ( )
{
  width  = 2;
  height = 3;
}

// overloaded constructor
Rectangle::Rectangle ( int a, int b )
{
  width  = a;
  height = b;
}

int main ( )
{
  // Two objects of class Rectangle are constructed: rectd and recto.
  // The object rectd is constructed using the default constructor
  // The object recto is constructed with two arguments (overloaded constructor)
  Rectangle recto ( 4, 5 );
  Rectangle rectd;  // empty parentheses cannot be used to call the default constructor

    std::cout << "rectangle area, default constructor:    " << rectd.area() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "expected answer:                        6 = 2 x 3\n" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "rectangle area, overloaded constructor: " << recto.area() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "expected answer:                        20 = 4 x 5"  << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Code compiles with g++; no need for C++11 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun I decided to do this in C#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();//length 2, width 1
        Rectangle yourRect = new Rectangle(12.34, 25.022);
        Console.WriteLine(rect.area() + " area of puny rect\n" + yourRect.area() + " area of bigger and better rect");
        Console.WriteLine(rect.perimeter() + " perimeter of puny rect\n" + yourRect.perimeter() + " perimeter of bigger and better!");
        //change things
        rect.length = 23.33;
        rect.width = 122222.333;
        Console.WriteLine(rect.area() + " WHOA look at that!\n" + rect.perimeter() + " WHHHAAATTT that is much bigger!");
        Console.ReadKey();//this is here to look at output without it disapearing.
    }

}
class Rectangle
{
    //simple rectangle class using C#
    /**
     * Using double will allow you to use decimals which 
     * is much more accurate than int
     * */
    public double width { get; set; }
    public double length { get; set; }

    public Rectangle()
    {
        this.length = 2.0;
        this.width = 1.0;
    }

    public Rectangle(double length, double width)
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }
    public double area()
    {
        return length * width;
    }
    public double perimeter()
    {
        return 2 * (length + width);
    }
}
```

Helpful little notes in the codes, enjoy. BTW I borrowed the basic design from Farooque's Java design above.

Answer (score 0):

```
//C++ CODE
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle{
private:
double length;
double breadth;
public:
Rectangle(){
    length=0;
    breadth=0;
}
Rectangle(double x,double y){
    length=x;
    breadth=y;
}
Rectangle(double lb){
    length=lb;
    breadth=lb;
}
void display(){
  cout<<"Area of rec. is "<<length*breadth<<endl;
}
};
int main(){
Rectangle r1;
Rectangle r2{ 10 };
Rectangle r3{ 15.6,45 };
r1.display();
r2.display();
r3.display();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).